# Creating modern style dynamic menu in Windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, menu

In my MFC dialog based application I have main menu created with Visual Studio resource editor, and in one place there is dynamic menu, created at run time. All parts of menu that are created with Visual studio have modern look, and my dynamically created sub-menu has old look, as shown in image below.

[image]

My code for creating dynamic sub-menu is something like this (not the real code, but real code is not all that important):

```
CMenu subMenu;
subMenu.CreateMenu();

for (...)
{
    subMenu.AppendMenu(
        MF_STRING | (isChecked ? MF_CHECKED : MF_UNCHECKED),
        <some menu ID>,
        <some menu text>);
}
```

Inserting this sub-menu to where it belongs is done like this (pretty much the actual code):

```
TCHAR szMenuString[256];
MENUITEMINFO mii;
mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_CHECKMARKS |
    MIIM_DATA | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_FTYPE;
mii.dwTypeData = szMenuString;
mii.cch = sizeof(szMenuString) / sizeof(szMenuString[0]);

GetMenu()->GetMenuItemInfo(ID_SUBMENU, &mii);
mii.fMask |= MIIM_SUBMENU;
mii.hSubMenu = subMenu.GetSafeHmenu();
GetMenu()->SetMenuItemInfo(ID_SUBMENU, &mii);
```

How can I create my sub-menu so that it appears the same in style as the rest of the main menu?

My code is written in MFC, but your answer does not have to be in MFC (and probably cannot be).

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of persuading recent versions of Windows to display old-style menus.  I've got an ancient MFC app with dynamic menus and it works fine.  You don't show the code that creates the menu.  Are you sure it isn't creating an owner-draw menu?

Comment: `CMenu` above is MFC class and its `CreateMenu` and `AppendMenu` functions are thin wrappers for [`CreateMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647624.aspx) and [`AppendMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616.aspx) winapi functions. My project was initially created in VS2003, and maybe there's some issue with manifest file. I'll check on that.

Comment: Not sure about this, but when I create popup menu, it is shown with proper theme, and not old style menu. To answer SO questions, I generally code them out, but this demands too much of it, so I am not giving it hands on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution, but don't really understand what was happening. The solution is to prevent calling `DestroyMenu` on `subMenu`'s destructor at the end of the function. This is done by either calling `subMenu.Detach()`, or making `subMenu` a pointer to `CMenu`.

What I don't understand is why is `DestroyMenu` turning new style menu to old style. I would expect that the menu is either destroyed and not shown, or copied in `SetMenuItemInfo` and so its style preserved. Whoever provides an answer to this one gets my vote :)

Also, I would like to know if I'm producing a resource leak by calling `Detach` here, or is my dynamic sub-menu destroyed along with the main menu. Points await the one who provides an answer.

Comment: Just came across this and thought of you!  You shouldn't have a resource leak because [destroying a top-level menu destroys submenus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/30/46594.aspx).  It doesn't explain why you get an old-style menu; maybe by destroying your submenu you're confusing Windows into thinking it is a horizontal menu (as described in the article).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. One question solved. I tested  CreatePopupMenu without Detach and old style menu still appears, so one mystery still exists.